# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{r=1}^m\cot^3\frac{r\pi}{2m+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> I would like to know the value of :
>
> $$\cot(x_1)^3+\cot(x_2)^3+\cot(x_3)^3+\cdots+\cot(x_m)^3 $$
>
> as a function of $m$ where $x_r$ is given by:
>
> $$x_r=\dfrac{r\pi}{2m+1}$$

I know that $$\cot(x_1)^2+\cot(x_2)^2+\cot(x_3)^2+\cdots+\cot(x_m)^2=\dfrac{2m(2m-1)}6$$

and was wondering if the cubes of those cotangents could be evaluated in closed form too.

Comment: I think it could be a good idea to submit the conjecture on the site. Moreover, the sequence $\{3,45,945,14175\}$ is in OEIS and it "seems" to be $A171080$. If you do not plan to do it, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If 
$$S_k=\sum _{n=1}^m \Big[\cot \left(\frac{n \,\pi  }{2 m+1}\right)\Big]^k$$ the only ones I found are (you have the first one)
$$S_2=\frac{1}{3} m (2 m-1)\qquad \text{and} \qquad S_4=\frac{1}{45} m (2 m-1) \left(4 m^2+10 m-9\right)$$

Working on my one (the different CAS I used were of no help for $k>4$), I found
$$S_6=\frac{1}{945} m (2 m-1)(32 m^4+112 m^3+8 m^2-252 m+135)$$
$$S_8=\frac{1}{14175} m (2 m-1)(192 m^6+864 m^5+496 m^4-2248 m^3-1388 m^2+3834 m-1575)$$

I was unable to find anything similar for odd values of $k$.

At least, you could make the conjecture that
$$S_{2k}=\frac{1}{a_k} m (2 m-1) P_{2(k-1)}(m)$$

Comment: thanks for your efforts but now that i think about it it makes sense that only even powers have a polynomial form because the cotangent produces square roots and so only the even powers can eliminate them.BUT that doesnt imply there isnt a non-integer function of m right?

Comment: also the conjecture is from your part go ahead:)

Comment: also would adding both of the sums give us an answer for that ? for example S1 + S3 = f(m) where f is a function of m.

Comment: @jace. Done in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479248